# Uiswitch does not change the state ios

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I have a problem with my `UISwitch`. When I select or deselect my switch `state(isHighlighted, selected)` is always 0. I'm using iOS 8.3.

```
- (IBAction)sliderOnOff:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_sliderOnOff.state);    
}
```

Log :

> 2015-04-27 22:41:50.617 Project[4011:179116] 0
>
> 2015-04-27 22:41:50.762 Project[4011:179116] 0
>
> 2015-04-27 22:41:50.972 Project[4011:179116] 0
>
> 2015-04-27 22:41:51.088 Project[4011:179116] 0
>
> 2015-04-27 22:41:51.226 Project[4011:179116] 0
>
> 2015-04-27 22:41:51.343 Project[4011:179116] 0

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the `on` property of the `UISwitch`.
What you currently read is the `UIControlState` aka `state` of the super class `UIControl` which informs you about selection, highlighting, etc.

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_sliderOnOff.on);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `on` property for UISwitch. So it's `switch.on`, not `switch.state`.

You might need to cast `id` to `UISwitch` first to access that property.